# how to maintain tkinter theme when toplevel with different theme is opened

Tags: python, tkinter, styles, themes

I have tkinter `root window` and `toplevel window` with different themes but when i open the `toplevel window` it changes the `root window` to the themes set for the `toplevel window`

I want to maintain the themes set for each window. This results in error `_tkinter.TclError: Theme MyStyle already exists` when i close the toplevel window and open it again.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk



def test2():
    rt1 = tk.Toplevel()
    rt1.geometry("500x500")

    s = ttk.Style()
    s.theme_create("MyStyle", parent="alt", settings={
    "TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0]}},
    "TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [50, 8] }}})

    s.theme_use("MyStyle")

    notebook = ttk.Notebook(rt1)

    f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, width=200, height=200)
    f2 = tk.Frame(notebook, width=200, height=200)

    notebook.add(f1, text="tab 1")
    notebook.add(f2, text="tab 2")

    notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")


tree = ttk.Treeview(root, column=("col1", "col2"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("deee", "fjfj","fjjf", "jfjfjf"))
tree.pack()

b3 = tk.Button(root, text="new", command=test2)
b3.place(x=200, y=200)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: *"_tkinter.TclError:"*: `Theme` can only to be **one** and defined **only once**. Therefore, define on `root`. Change to `"Toplevel.TNotebook": ...` to define a **not** app wide `style`. Apply it using `ttk.Notebook(rt1, style='Toplevel.TNotebook')`

Comment: dont understand

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are trying to create a style every time the button is pressed and this is what is causing the problem.

Instead just move the theme creation to the the global namespace where it can be created once and it wont be an issue anymore.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def test2():
    rt1 = tk.Toplevel()
    rt1.geometry("500x500")
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(rt1)
    f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, width=200, height=200)
    f2 = tk.Frame(notebook, width=200, height=200)
    notebook.add(f1, text="tab 1")
    notebook.add(f2, text="tab 2")
    notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, column=("col1", "col2"))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=("deee", "fjfj","fjjf", "jfjfjf"))
tree.pack()

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_create("MyStyle", parent="alt", settings={
"TNotebook": {"configure": {"tabmargins": [2, 5, 2, 0]}},
"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [50, 8] }}})
s.theme_use("MyStyle")

b3 = tk.Button(root, text="new", command=test2)
b3.place(x=200, y=200)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i want the `root window` theme to be different from the `toplevel window` by keeping the dafault `treeview` style .

Comment: The point in ttk style is to have a consistent theme through the entire app. So what you are trying to do defeats the purpose of ttk widgets. If I get a sec I will see if I can figure something out for this but it might be later today.